# Trouble with Controllers to manipulate an Object inside a Service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I have an object which should be accessible in many controllers.

This object is inside a Service, has **default values**  and the controller might change those values later.

**My problem** is that my object inside the service keep values changed by controllers.

When a controller get the object, I want always that it takes the object with default values. (not with values previously modified by an other controller before...)

I have this inside my service :

```
this.myObject = {'item1' : 'something', 'item2' : 'other' , .....};
```

I know that it's not correct because of `this.`

So I tried to make a method like this :

```
this.createMyObject = function() {
  var obj = myObject;
  return obj;
}
```

And call `createMyObject();` in my controllers but this doesn't work too.

I know that the solution might be obvious.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is a *copy* of `myObject`, what you want to do is :

```
var obj = angular.copy(myObject);
```

Because `var obj = myObject;` will just copy the reference of the object, not its content.

Answer (score 1):

`Object` in Javascript are pass by reference unless copied or cloned. So when you are doing

```
this.createMyObject = function() {
  var obj = myObject;
  return obj;
}
```

The reference of `myObject` is getting assigned to `obj` hence, any change in `obj` will update the `myObject` as well.

Consider using [angular.extend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend) or [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)

```
this.createMyObject = function() {
  var obj = {};
  angular.copy(myObject, obj);
  // or
  // obj = angular.copy(myObject);
  return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below solution:

### Service Code:

```
.service('MyService', function() {
    var myObject = {
                    'item1': '',
                    'items2': ''
    };


    /**
     * Used to return copy of myObject with some default values
     */
    this.createMyObject = function() {
        return angular.copy(myObject);
    };

    this.alterMyObject = function() {
        // @TODO here myObject can be used to edit directly
    };
});
```

Note:
"=" operator between two object just used to assign reference of RHS obj to LHS. So any further changes with LHS object will be reflected to RHS obj also.